# how to make navbar collapse after click one link in one page

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

so I have navbar dropdown that link to another pages and in this page too (link to one page), but why the collapse function on my navbar cant work?

this is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../content/main.php#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../content/emblem.php">Emblem</a></li>
            <li><a href="../content/history.php">History</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">The Games <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games2">Water</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games3">Non-Water</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

this code is still link to this page

```
<li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">The Games <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games2">Water</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games3">Non-Water</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

my question is how make the collapse work?

Comment: where is your jquery code?

Comment: Please check if you have installed either **bootstrap.js** or **bootstrap.min.js** in your application and have referenced it in your layout or main page. Nav collapse is a part of **bootstrap.js**

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal I used bootstrap.min.js, so how make it collapse?

Comment: @KhoirulZ have you checked it in mobile version because the collapse functionality only show in mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

This will collapse your navbar:

CSS File:

```css
/* To Dropdown navbar dropdown on hover */
.navbar-nav > li:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #ccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    
        <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


              
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>


    <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="../content/main.php#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../content/emblem.php">Emblem</a></li>
            <li><a href="../content/history.php">History</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">The Games <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games2">Water</a></li>
                    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.in" href="#games3">Non-Water</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


    </nav>


    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have a all that stylesheet include: You just only need bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css the stylesheet1 is the example below.